# An AngularJs element directive that has no DOM presence

Tags: angularjs

The issue with hidden elements that they still impact the layout flow of css selectors such as `:first-child`.  I want my directive to be declared as an element `restrict: 'E'`, produce no disruptive DOM elements and create its own isolate scope.  Could this be done somehow by generating a comment to hang the directive scope upon?  It appears that you are not allowed to have a template that uses single comment.

I want to use this directive to be able to conditionally genereate and show DOM content as needed.  And when not needed, to have no DOM presence.  For example, i have a list directive that uses `ng-repeat` and is wrapped with a div container.  If there are no items to show in the list i want the entire div counter to be non-present.

Avoiding using `:first-child` is possible, but seems like a klunky work-around.  More generally, its seems like a useful and efficient feature to be able to place 'E' directives in your pages that know their location but dont enter the DOM until required.  I'm surprised that has not been a more requested feature.

Comment: What do you want your directive to do if there's no DOM element? The whole point of [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is to modify the content on the page.

Comment: I edited to add a response to your question.

Comment: It's still not clear, but I suspect the best answer is to rewrite your CSS to account for the empty directive element.

Comment: added a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and satisfying answer to this.  Do what ng-if and others do, create a comment element, insert it as a placeholder, and then remove the original directive.  That way, the directive has no DOM visible presence and will not interfere with css classes, yet is still aware of its location in the event it needs to insert or modify the DOM as a later point.